# How can I convert an NSString to an Int?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsstring, swift

I'm completely new to Apple programming, but I thought Swift looked interesting after reading about it. I'm trying to make a simple number guessing game on a command line, but I can't get it to convert an integer to a string. I've tried searching the internet a lot for a way to do this, but I have no idea what's wrong. I don't want to just directly accept the user's input as an integer, I'd rather convert it from a string to an integer to make it easier to deal with errors (like how it's done in Python). This is what I did:

```
import Foundation
// Get Input
let standardInput = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
// Convert to int function
func convertToInt(guess: String) -> Int {
    var num: Int = guess.toInt()! // It tells me "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" on this line and the program stops
    return num
}
println("Please enter your name.")
// Get the user's name
let data = standardInput.availableData
var name = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
println("Hello \(name)")
println("Please enter a number and I will try to guess it.")
// Get the user's number
let data2 = standardInput.availableData
var number = NSString(data: data2, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
// Call the function to convert the number to an int
var newnum = convertToInt(number)
println(newnum)
```

After running this, it tells me

```
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None (lldb)
```

in the debug area. I have no idea how to fix this. Is there any way to convert a number directly from `NSString` to `Int`?

Comment: Have you checked out [NSNumber?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Have you checked out [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)?

Answer (score 2):

there are several problems with your code but to answer the question at hand, the problem is with your misuse of optionals (which is covered in the introduction to swift video from wwdc).

the toInt method returns an optional and not an Int.  Optionals are the answer to the question: "What if the string i'm trying to convert isn't a number, what should be returned?"  The same thing goes for trying to access a key from a dictionary that isn't there.  In the objective-c world we return nil, but in Swift it's optional.  What you need to do is check to see if a value came back, and if so you can use it.  For example

```
 if let number = guess.toInt() {
      //now we can do something with number because we know conversion worked
      println(number)
 } else {
      println("a number wasn't entered")
 }
```

Comment: And I'd highly recommend to Jeremy to either download and read the Swift book, or watch the WWDC videos, to actually understand this code so that it's not just some magic.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, `toInt()` method is removed. Use `Int()` method.

For example:

```
var tempInt :Int  = Int("24")!
```

Answer (score 1):

The `toInt` method returns an Optional. You should check that a value was returned before using it.

```
var name: String = NSString(string: "1234")
var integer:Int? = name.toInt()
if let integer = integer {
    println("\(integer)")
}
```

You could also use `NSNumberFormatter` to get a number from the string. Note this returns an `NSNumber`, but you can cast it to a Swift `Int` easily.

```
var numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
var number:NSNumber? = numberFormatter.numberFromString("1234")
if let number = number {
    var integer = Int(number)
    println("\(integer)")
}
```

`toInt` and `numberFromString` return Optionals. If the string can't be converted to a number, they return `nil`.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need the `as String`; you can use the weaker `let name: String = x` as the compiler will implicitly (rather than explicitly) convert. This is safer as it will give a compile-time error if `x` is, say, of type Any but not if x is an NSString (unlike as, which will give a runtime error). (In fact the OP's code does exactly this and the compiler makes it work.)

Comment: Thanks, very good to know. Updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: So I wrote this function based on that answer:

    **func convertToInt(guess: String) -> Int {
        var num: Int? = guess.toInt()
        if let num = num {
            return num
        }
        else {
            return 1
        }
    }**

The problem is, whenever I enter a number, the fuction returns 1, meaning no conversion was made (I'm guessing).

Answer (score 1):

```
 var numberFormatter:NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = ",";
    numberFormatter.groupingSize = 3;
    var number:String? = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(numberFormatter.numberFromString("15487787878787")!)
```